# What's a class handler callback in Objective-C runtime?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

What's a class handler callback in Objective-C runtime? As per the documentation,

> [objc_getClass](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418952-objc_getclass?language=objc) is different from objc_lookUpClass in that if the class is not registered, objc_getClass calls the class handler callback and then checks a second time to see whether the class is registered. objc_lookUpClass does not call the class handler callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be an obsolete feature of the runtime.  In /usr/include/objc/runtime.h, you can find the following declaration in a section labeled `/* Obsolete functions */`:

```
OBJC_EXPORT void objc_setClassHandler(int (*)(const char *)) OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
```

So, apparently, one could, before Objective-C 2.0, register a function pointer to act as the class handler. I guess the parameter is the class name. It would have the opportunity to load or dynamically create the named class.

Comment: In PyObjC, I played with this mechanism to allow Python classes to be dynamically realized in the ObjC runtime when first referenced.   It worked, but there proved to be much easier ways of doing this.    Ultimately, lazy initialization in this fashion just wasn't that valuable, which is why it was deprecated.